# Possible covariance matrices of predictions of a stationary process

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a discrete time zero-mean real-valued stationary Gaussian process adapted to a $\sigma$-field ${F}_t$. Let us define

$Z_{t,j} \equiv \mathbb{E}[X_{t+j}|{F}_t]$

I am interested in understanding the set of possible $k \times k$ covariance matrices

$S\equiv\{\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}: \Sigma_{j,k} = \mathbb{E}[Z_{t,j}Z_{t,k}] \}$

as we vary over all possible stationary processes.

1. Note that $S$ does not depend on $t$ due to stationarity.
2. Note that $S$ is a strict subset of the set of all positive semi-definite (symmetric) matrices. In particular, we must have
   $\Sigma_{1,1} \geq \Sigma_{2,2} \geq \ldots \geq \Sigma_{k,k}$ because, informally, our prediction of $X_t$ only gets better as $t$ draws nearer. We can generalize this idea to generate a bigger set of constraints which the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ must satisfy: e.g., we have that our prediction of $X_t + \alpha X_{t+1}$ only gets better as $t$ draws nearer, hence, for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\Sigma_{j,j} + 2\alpha \Sigma_{j,j+1} + \alpha^2 \Sigma_{j+1,j+1}\geq \Sigma_{j+1,j+1} + 2\alpha \Sigma_{j+1,j+2} + \alpha^2 \Sigma_{j+2,j+2}$ for all $j=1,2,\dots$. (This set of constraints may be described as positive semidefiniteness of the difference between a pair of principal submatrices of $\Sigma$.)

Are there any other constraints that the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ must satisfy apart from those described above? Can one have a clean characterization of $S$?